# Do I require a clustered file system to share a LUN via VMWare?

Tags: vmware-server, share, lun

I want to avoid this:

[How can I use NTFS and iSCSI and not corrupt my SAN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/295190/how-can-i-use-ntfs-and-iscsi-and-not-corrupt-my-san)

On possbility I may have is to share out a LUN from my SAN and have other machines access that shared drive.  In other words, VMWare will present it to other machines as a drive that it has natively.

Do I require a clustered file system for that as well?  Will my writes still be "dirty"?

Comment: I think you need to rethink your strategy it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

VMware isn't a file share mount.  If you want a file server add the LUN to VMware and create a VM to run as the file server and give that VM space on the LUN (or the entire LUN as an RDM).